# AWS EC2 / Elastic Beanstalk | How to white list by domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, whitelist

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment which is a Node API. I also have a Angular web app outside of AWS on domain: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

How would I go about making it so only calls made from 'www.example.com' to the AWS environment(Node API can be accessed?

I am familiar with AWS security groups but it doesn't handle domain whitelisting (Only IP's). Since users will be on different IP's using [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) I need to whitelist by domain and not IP.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is your app integrated by the other app? API, iFrame, embedding assets (i.e. images, css, js only)

Comment: Angular web app uses HTTP requests to Node API. Also note there is no data held in AWS (database, buckets, etc). The concept of what I'm trying to achieve seems to be common but I cant find this feature in AWS. I appreciate your help 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without blocking via IP your only choice is to look at attaching a [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) to the [ALB in your Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://medium.com/finnovate-io/setting-up-aws-web-application-firewall-waf-with-elastic-beanstalk-6243dc7755ea).

By doing this you can allow only traffic that matches a set of conditions, if there is a particular header that your requests include when they make requests to the backend then you can allow requests from these sources.

Assuming the request to the API is made from the frontend you should have a [referrer header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) which contains the source of the previous page. You could whitelist this domain in the WAF.

Comment: To clarify, when you say " whitelist this domain in the WAF" do you mean there is an actual whitelist by domain feature in WAF or do you mean use WAF's string/regex match feature and create a rule to match the string of my domain to the referrer header?

Comment: You would have to create your own rule to whitelist the domain :).

Comment: Worked exactly as stated!

Comment: Is there a way to set up a `config` file for beanstalk like in here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-host-attacks/ to whitelist a domain?

Comment: Hmm yea this feature in the article seems like the opposite. I wish you could just block all and only allow certain domains.